# FlowJS - gives a type error because it cannot recognize the result of a `typeof` statement

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The following code results in an error:

```
type NextItem = string | { [string]: string };

const next: NextItem = 'foo';
const isString = typeof next === 'string';
const toName = isString ? next : Object.keys(next)[0];
                                 ^ string [1] is not an object.
```

but getting rid of the `isString` variable fixes it:

```
type NextItem = string | { [string]: string };

const next: NextItem = 'foo';
const toName = typeof next === 'string' ? next : Object.keys(next)[0];
```

I understand *why*, but I'm hoping that someone might offer a better solution. I need to reuse the `isString` variable and would like to keep my code both DRY and SIMPLE (easy to read). So no "clever" (hacky) solutions please.

Comment: Can you use nesting to run all of the string code in its own block, e.g. `if (typeof next === 'string') { /* all the string stuff */ } else { /* all the object stuff */ }`?

Comment: Maybe, that's a tangible solution. It results in more code (longer form of a ternary), but at least it works. Do you mind posting an answer, as that's the only viable solution I have found to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow's refinements are generally based on direct checks at the time of use, so it will only ever see your `isString` variable as a `boolean` with no special meaning.

That leaves you with a few separate options:

- Tweak the control flow of your code so there are two clear branches, assuming there are many more checks for `isString`, you can always make a clear branch to handle both cases.
- Inline the `typeof next === 'string'` check.

  ```
  const toName = typeof next === 'string' ? next : Object.keys(next)[0];
  ```
- Use a [predicate function](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions) to centralize the `isString` logic

  ```
  function isString(arg: mixed): boolean %checks {
     return typeof arg === "string"; 
  }

  const toName = isString(next) ? next : Object.keys(next)[0];
  ```

Comment: The utility method (option 3) is the winner. I did not know about predicates in flowtype yet. Thanks!